# Is it possible to make a div unclick-throughable?

Tags: html, css, click

In this example is it possible to click the blue box without affecting the red box without using js?

http://codepen.io/YikesItsMikes/pen/MaPBJy

HTML

```
<div id="boxone">
  <div id="boxtwo"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#boxone{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
#boxtwo{
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 999;
}

#boxone:active{
  background: yellow; 
}
#boxtwo:active{
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: Not possible with the current HTML where #boxone wraps #boxtwo. You could layer the HTML so that #boxtwo is on top of #boxone without nesting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with the current HTML where #boxone wraps #boxtwo.

You could layer the HTML so that #boxtwo is on top of #boxone without nesting it like this;
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNVaWV

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}

#boxone{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#boxtwo{
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#boxone:active{
  background: yellow; 
}
#boxtwo:active{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="boxone"></div>
  <div id="boxtwo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn, seemed like something that should be possible. Well thanks anyway! I'll mark it answered in a bit, just want to see if anyone can come up with another way to get around this.